# Strange log scale on a plot. How do I read this?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

Doing an assignment with a strange log-log data plot. You'll notice that there at 14 segments per cycle, and they are not spaced as usual. Note the last 4 segments break the pattern of reduced spacing. I am at a loss as to how to read values from this.

Does each space represent 1/14th of the value of the cycle? Any ideas would help!!

[image: A strange log-log plot.]

Comment: Maybe the marks between 0.1 and 1 are .15, .2, .25, .3, .35, .4, .45, .5, .55, .6, .7, .8, .9?

Comment: That just might be it, with the half-line (i.e. linear average) not stated for the last 4 because of space constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a ruler and estimate the percentage of the distance from $0.1$ to $1.0$
at which each mark lies.
The mark for $0.2$ will be at $30$% of the distance,
the mark for $0.4$ at $60$% of the distance,
the mark for $0.5$ at $70$% of the distance, and
the mark for $0.8$ at $90$% of the distance.
(Nothing mysterious about this; these are just the base-ten
logarithms of $2,4,5,$ and $8$ times $100$%.)
The mark for $0.3$ will be just before the halfway point.

Just estimating these percentages by eye, it appears that the comments are correct:
the marks appear to be at
$0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8,$ and $0.9.$